# How is memory managed in YugaByte DB?

Tags: database, distributed-database, yugabytedb

How is memory is managed in YugaByte DB? I understand that there are two sets of processes `yb-tserver` & `yb-master`, but couldn't find too many other details.

Specific questions:

1. How much RAM do each of these processes use by default?
2. Is there a way to explicitly control this?
3. Presumably, the memory is used for caching, memtables etc. How are these components sized?
4. Can specific tables be pinned in memory (or say given higher priority in caches)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

1. How much RAM do each of these processes use by default?

By default:

- yb-tserver process assumes 85% of node's RAM is available for its use.
  and
- yb-master process assumes 10% of node's RAM is available for its use.

These are determined by default settings of the gflag
`--default_memory_limit_to_ram_ratio` (0.85 and 0.1 respectively for
yb-tserver/yb-master).

2. Is there a way to explicitly control this?

Yes, there are 2 different options for controlling how much memory is allocated to the processes yb-master and yb-tserver:

Option A) You can set `--default_memory_limit_to_ram_ratio` to control
what percentage of node's RAM the process should use.

Option B) You can specify an absolute value too using
`--memory_limit_hard_bytes`. For example, to give yb-tserver 32GB of
RAM, use:

`--memory_limit_hard_bytes 34359738368`

Since you start these two processes independently, you can use either option for yb-master or yb-tserver. Just make sure that you don't oversubscribe total machine memory since a yb-master and a yb-tserver process can be present on a single VM.

3. Presumably, the memory is used for caching, memtables etc. How are
   these components sized?

Yes, the primary consumers of memory are the block cache, memstores &
memory needed for requests/RPCs in flight.

Block Cache:
`--db_block_cache_size_percentage=50 (default)`

Total memstore is the minimum of these two knobs:
`--global_memstore_size_mb_max=2048`
`--global_memstore_size_percentage=10`

4. Can specific tables be pinned in memory (or say given higher
   priority in caches)?

We currently (as of 1.1) do not have per-table pinning hints yet.
However, the block cache does do a great job already by default of
keeping hot blocks in cache. We have enhanced RocksDB’s block cache to
be scan resistant. The motivation was to prevent operations such as
long-running scans (e.g., due to an occasional large query or
background Spark jobs) from polluting the entire cache with poor
quality data and wiping out useful/hot data.